# Quadratic-exponential integral divided by $x^2$. How to solve?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is it possible to solve the following integral?

$$\int_a^b \frac{e^{-x^2-c x}}{x^2} dx$$

(where $c$ is a positive number)

I tried both with Mathematica and looking on an integral table (Gradshtein's big book) and I wasn't able to find an answer.

EDIT:

I've been asked to add a bit of context to this question.
I'm trying to calculate the solution of the 1D diffusion equation for arbitrary initial condition and inhomogeneous term independent on time:

$$\rho_t=D\rho_{xx}+v\rho_x+\phi\rho+\epsilon(x)$$
with a change of variable you reduce it to
$$f_t=D f_{xx}+\eta(x)$$
where $\eta(x,t)=\epsilon(x) e^{-\phi t}$

if $\phi$ is set to zero, $\eta$ would be independent on time.

The integral I've presented you is the time-integral of the one in Eq. 1.17 of
[http://www-m6.ma.tum.de/~kuttler/script_reaktdiff.pdf](http://www-m6.ma.tum.de/%7Ekuttler/script_reaktdiff.pdf)
the coefficient $c$ in the integral is proportional to $\phi$, and I need it to impose degradation of the particles of my random walk.

I hope now the frame of the problem is a bit more clear .

Comment: Can you please show the work you have done so far.

Comment: For the first you can use incomplete gamma function

Comment: Have you tried Feynman technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral has no elementary solution, and it's a problem also because to the unknown nature of the limits $a$ and $b$.
One way to attack the problem, under some assumptions, is the following:

- First we complete the square by supposing there does exist $d$ and $p$ such that
  $$e^{-x^2 - cx} = e^{-(x^2+cx)} = e^{-(x^2 + cx + d - d)} = e^{d}\ e^{-(x+p)^2}$$

Where of course $c = 2p$ and $d = p^2$.

This being said, the integral reads

$$e^{d}\int_a^b \dfrac{e^{-(x+p)^2}}{x^2}\ \text{d}x$$

Due to the unknown nature of the limit, we shouldn't proceed.
Yet with some poker face, assuming we can, we develop a Taylor Series for the exponential term, which brings us to

$$e^{d}\int_a^b \dfrac{1}{x^2}\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!} (x + p)^{2k}\ \text{d}x = $$

$$ = e^d \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!} \int_a^b \dfrac{(x+p)^{2k}}{x^2}\ \text{d}x$$

The general integral can be calculated in terms of Hypergeometric Functions:

$$\int \dfrac{(x+p)^{2k}}{x^2}\ \text{d}x = \frac{(p+x)^{2 k+1} \, _2F_1\left(2,2 k+1;2 k+2;\frac{x}{p}+1\right)}{(2 k+1) p^2} = G(k,p,x)$$

Adding the limits $a$, $b$ means just to take $G(k,p, b) - G(k, p,a)$.

Eventually the result is expressed in terms of a Series of Hypergeometric Functions.

Not something nice for sure, but for the lovers of numerical methods it might work!

$$e^d \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k \left((b+p)^{2 k+1} \, _2F_1\left(2,2 k+1;2 k+2;\frac{b+p}{p}\right)-(a+p)^{2 k+1} \, _2F_1\left(2,2 k+1;2 k+2;\frac{a+p}{p}\right)\right)}{(2 k+1) p^2 k!}$$

---

---

---

The first term is

$$\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}$$

The second term is

$$-\frac{p^2}{a}+2 p \log \left(-\frac{a}{p}\right)+a+\frac{p^2}{b}-2 p \log \left(-\frac{b}{p}\right)-b$$

The third term is

$$\frac{1}{6} \left(-a^3-6 a^2 p+\frac{3 p^4}{a}-12 p^3 \log \left(-\frac{a}{p}\right)-18 a p^2+b^3+6 b^2 p-\frac{3 p^4}{b}+12 p^3 \log \left(-\frac{b}{p}\right)+18 b p^2\right)$$

Putting them together so far you can write down the first three terms of the series as

$$-\frac{a^3}{6}-a^2 p+\frac{p^4}{2 a}-3 a p^2-\frac{p^2}{a}-2 \left(p^2-1\right) p \log \left(-\frac{a}{p}\right)+a+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{b^3}{6}+b^2 p-\frac{p^4}{2 b}+3 b p^2+\frac{p^2}{b}+2 \left(p^2-1\right) p \log \left(-\frac{b}{p}\right)-b-\frac{1}{b}$$

And so on. As I specified: this solution couldn't work due to the unknownness of $a$ and $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 0):

Starting fro @Turing's answer, considering $$I=\int\dfrac{e^{-(x+p)^2}}{x^2}\, dx$$ We could expand the numerator as a Taylor series around $p=0$. This would give
$$e^{-(x+p)^2}=e^{-x^2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ Q_n(x)}{n!}\, p^n$$ where $Q_n(x)$ are polynomials of degree $n$ in $x$ (all coefficients being integer numbers).

For example, summing only four terms and grouping, we should have as integrand

$$e^{-x^2}\,\, \big[\frac {a_0} {x^2}+\frac {a_1} {x}+ {a_2} +{a_3} x+a_4 {x^2}\big]$$ where

$$a_0=\frac{p^4-2 p^2+2}{2} \qquad \qquad a_1=2 p \left(p^2-1\right)$$
$$a_2=-2 p^2
   \left(p^2-1\right)\qquad \qquad a_3=-\frac{4 p^3 }{3}\qquad \qquad a_4=\frac{2 p^4}{3}$$ and now we face integrals
$$J_n=\int x^{n-2}\,e^{-x^2}\,dx=-\frac{1}{2} \Gamma \left(\frac{n-1}{2},x^2\right)$$

For a very modest test, let $p=1$, $a=1$ and $b=2$ using $12$ terms. The approximation gives $0.003028$ while numerical integration gives $0.003012$.